# Print / structures / pointers

Tags: c, pointers, operators, structure

I need help solving this problem in my mind so if anyone had a similar problem it would help me a lot.

Problem is:

Let the type be defined:

```
typedef struct t
{ 
   char c; char *p;
} T;
```

What will the following code print?

```
T* const tx=0, ty[5], *tz[5];
printf("tx:%d\n", sizeof(tx));
printf("ty:%d\n", sizeof(ty));
printf("tz:%d\n", sizeof(tz));
```

The program prints:

```
tx=4
ty=40
tz=20
```

What interests me is why is the print like this?

The first variable of type `tx` is of the type of structure `T`, which indicates a constant value which is zero.
As far as I understand, it is necessary to do a sizeof of the value indicated by the variable tx, it depends on the machine I use, so it is 4.

Also for the third printout it is necessary to do a sizeof of the value pointed by `tz`, since on my machine the sizeof of the pointer is equal to 4, here we have 5 elements of the array so it is equal to 20.

For the second print I have no idea why it prints 40?

Is my thinking correct for the first and third print?

If anyone is willing to explain to me why the second printout is 40, I would  be grateful?

Thanks in advance !

Best regards !

Comment: First of all, the correct `printf` format specifier for the type `size_t` (which is the result of the `sizeof` operator) is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: With that said, the variable `tx` is a *pointer* so `sizeof tx` is the size of the pointer not what it points to. The variable `ty` is an array of five `T` objects, where each structure is 8 bytes (see [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)). And the last variable `tz` is an array of five pointers.

Answer (score 2):

`T* const tx=0, …` declares `tx` to be a `const` pointer to a `T`, so `sizeof tx` is the size of a pointer to a structure.

`T* const tx=0, ty[5],…` declares `ty` to be an array of 5 `T`, so `sizeof ty` is the size of 5 such structures or 5 times the size of one such structure. Note that the C grammar structures the declaration `T* const tx=0, ty[5],…` as:

- `T` is a *declaration-specifier* that here contains only a *type-specifier*.
- `* const tx=0` is an *init-declarator-list* in which `* const tx` is the *declarator* and `0` is the *initializer*.
- `ty[5]` is another *init-declarator-list* that contains just the declarator `ty[5]` and no *initializer*.

Note that `* const tx` groups together; the `*` goes with `const tx`, not with `T`. So writing this as `T* const tx=0, ty[5], *tz[5];` rather than `t * const tx=0, ty[5], *tz[5];` portrays the grammatical grouping incorrectly. `ty` is an array of `T`, not an array of `T*`.

`T* const tx=0, ty[5], *tz[5];` declares `tz` to be an array of 5 pointers to `T`, so `sizeof tz` is the size of 5 pointers to structures.

You do not need parentheses when using `sizeof` with options; `sizeof tx` suffices. And you should print sizes using the `%zu` conversion, not `%d`, so the `printf` statements can be:

```
printf("The size of tx is %zu bytes.\n", sizeof tx);
printf("The size of ty is %zu bytes.\n", sizeof ty);
printf("The size of tz is %zu bytes.\n", sizeof tz);
```